# pyenv: poetry itself, running on older python version, what to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry, pyenv

Update:

Which Python should I use to install poetry?

- System Python: That is an excellent idea. Once, however, `poetry self update` was trying to update a system package without the necessary permissions.
- Pyenv: A good solution. Nonetheless, if Python is updated and the old installation is deleted, poetry will stop working because it is not aware of the new python version.

---

- Set global python with pyenv

`pyenv global 3.10.7`

- Install poetry

`$ curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -`

- Change global python

`pyenv global 3.10.8`

Now, `poetry` still runs on `Python-3.10.7`. If I uninstall this python version, poetry crashes.

How can I instruct the virtual environment of poetry to use the new python version?

A solution is to uninstall and reinstall it:

```
$ curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
$ curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: There is no "upgrade" / "transfer" behavior, if that's what you're looking for. If you're upgrading your global python, you'll have to reinstall `poetry`, at least TMK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision is to use Pyenv to install Poetry.

If the older python version should be deleted:

- Uninstall Poetry.
- Delete old Python version.
- Install Poetry.

Answer (score 2):

By default Poetry will use the Python version used during it installation to create a new venv.

Set the (experimental) config option [virtualenvs.prefer-active-python](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsprefer-active-python-experimental) to `true`, if you want Poetry to pick up the current activated Python version.

As an alternative to this option, run `poetry env use </path/to/python>` once before any other Poetry command, to set the python interpreter that should be used. See https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/#switching-between-environments

Comment: I undrestand and this experimental option is very useful. However I am trying to find out if I can detach poetry itself from the python version it is using which is the one it has been installed with. I have updated my question.